# Httpcleint 4.3.2 issue with default endpoint having explicit port 80

Tags: java

We are having a piece of code which tries to make a post request using HttpClient.execute with http://example.com:80 (I know it doesn't makes sense but it is there) and it gives socket connection error. With the older javaclient library this issue is not happening. Any suggestions to include the default port number and make successful call to an endpoint?

Comment: Can you post a stack trace of the error

Comment: Ports below and including 1024 require elevated privileges to run (or an account that is in a group that can directly access those ports).

Comment: class java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Comment: @Makato The *server* uses port 80 and usually (depending on OS) requires privilege. The *client* (by default) uses a transient port and can connect *to* 80 without privilege. How do you think nearly every web browser works?